# Sending blank input for drop down through .csv file in monkeytalk

Tags: android, monkeytalk

I have created a .csv file with all positive and negative inputs. I have provided "----" for blank inputs but monkeytalk does not consider it as a blank. Can some one help me for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Don't give it like "----"

Just put  "" (i.e. double quotes without space)and it would work.